# How to get org-mode not to change fold-state upload loading?

Tags: org-mode

I sometimes edit org files in non-org-mode. (e.g artist mode).

Upon returning to org-mode, it will mess with the fold/collapse state.
E.g it will collapse all headers so that I loose my current spot and have to find it again.

I tried editing `org-startup-folded` and tried all the 4 options, but all of these mess with the collapse state in some way or another. I cannot find an  option to leave expanded state as is when loading org-mode.

Is this possible?

Comment: You may wish to consider using an indirect buffer for artist mode stuff, which will permit you to have different modes in each buffer.  You may also be interested in the function show-all.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the indirect buffer. That actually works rather well. There hasn't been a reply on this and I don't think there seems to be away either. If you post an answer I'll accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet shows (in part) what happens when `org-mode` is enabled: `. . . (unless org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff (org-set-startup-visibility)) . . .`  The variable `org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff` is *undocumented* (i.e., there is no doc-string) and it has an initial default value of `nil`.  The original poster may wish to try *globally* setting this variable to `t` as follows:

```
(setq org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff t)
```

---

The following should also work by setting `org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff` to `t` on a let-bound -- *temporary* -- basis:

```
(defun enable-org-mode ()
"Turn on org-mode with `org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff' set to `t` on
a let-bound -- i.e., temporary -- basis."
(interactive)
  (let ((org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff t))
    (org-mode)))
```

---

If the original poster prefers not using the undocumented variable `org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff`, an alternative solution would be to use an `indirect-buffer` when working in `artist-mode`:

```
M-x make-indirect-buffer RET base-buffer RET indirect-name RET
```

The link to the manual that describes `indirect-buffer` is as follows:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html

---

It may behoove someone to send an email to the `org-mode` team suggesting that they document the variable `org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff`.

Comment: Unfortunatley the `org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff` didn't have an impact, but I hacked myself something together with the indirect buffer suggestion that kinda works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of org-startup-folded, use an equivalent in-buffer setting to force org-mode to one of the four states. For example, insert this line at the top of the org file:

```
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

and you will be able to open the org file fully expanded. As long as you don't edit that line while in artist mode, you'll get the behavior as specified in startup directive.

Comment: The issue here is that it changes the current fold state. showeverything expands everything. I would like org-mode not to change the exapand state when it re-loads or get's activated from antother mod like artist mod.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev, what you describe is the default behavior. That means you have to unset the org-startup-folded state in your current org-mode setup. You may also have to look into anything else changing that var (for example through your init file). Apologies if I've misunderstood your problem.

Comment: In the sense that either one of the 4 options for #+STARTUP: will change the fold state in some way or another. I'm looking for a way for it to leave the buffer 'as is' when re-loading org-mode.

Comment: Then don't use any #+STARTUP or init or customization settings to alter that behavior. By default org-mode leaves everything 'as is.' Those settings are used when you do not want 'as is'. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Actually, the default behavior that occurs when enabling `org-mode` is as follows:  `. . . (unless org-inhibit-startup-visibility-stuff (org-set-startup-visibility)) . . .`  For more details on what is actually happening when enabling `org-mode`, type `M-x find-function RET org-mode RET` and also type `M-x find-function RET org-set-startup-visibility RET` and review the source code.